# Unable to catch InvalidOperationException in xUnit

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, xunit

I've been trying to make the following test pass for the last hour, but I can't seem to make it work:

```cs
[Fact]
public async void TestDetachedRecordsArentUpdatedWithoutIDs()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ClientContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "cant_update_detached_clients_with_bankinfos")
        .Options;

    int clientID, bankInfoID;
    using(var context = new ClientContext(options))
    {
        var service = new ClientService(context);
        var bankInfo = new BankInfo { RoutingNumber = "12345" };
        var client = new Client { FirstName = "Javier", LastName = "Garcia", BankInfo = bankInfo };
        await service.Save(client);
        clientID = client.ID;
        bankInfoID = client.BankInfo.ID;
    }

    using(var context = new ClientContext(options))
    {
        var service = new ClientService(context);
        var bankInfo = new BankInfo { RoutingNumber = "Modified" };
        var client = new Client { ID = clientID, FirstName = "Modified", BankInfo = bankInfo };

        try
        {
            await service.Save(client);
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            var expected = "The property 'ID' on entity type 'BankInfo' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified.";
            Assert.Contains(expected, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm finding is that I can't seem to catch the exception. This is the result of the test every time I run it:

[image]

To give a little extra context, when `ClientService::Save` is called, it calls a method called `HandleDisconnectedEntities`, which blows up when the below line runs:

```
94:  _context.Entry(existingClient.BankInfo).CurrentValues.SetValues(client.BankInfo);
```

I do understand the nature of the exception, but I don't understand why my test would not be able to catch it. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you're erroring on the save in the try catch block? You have another **await service.Save(client);** above which is not being handled by the try catch. Perhaps that one is throwing so your test never asserts...?

Comment: @marko Yeah. I tried adding the ID to the `bankInfo` record in the second call and the exception would stop triggering, so I'm positive it's the one wrapped around the try-catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue because of the `async void` of the test definition.

```
public async void TestDetachedRecordsArentUpdatedWithoutIDs() { ...
```

> Async void methods have different error-handling semantics. When an exception is thrown out of an `async Task` or `async Task<T>` method, that exception is captured and placed on the Task object. With `async void` methods, there is no `Task` object, so any exceptions thrown out of an `async void` method will be raised directly on the `SynchronizationContext` that was active when the `async void` method started.
>
> Exceptions from an Async Void Method Can’t Be Caught with Catch

For example

```
private async void ThrowExceptionAsync()
{
  throw new InvalidOperationException();
}

public void AsyncVoidExceptions_CannotBeCaughtByCatch()
{
  try
  {
    ThrowExceptionAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    // The exception is never caught here!
    throw;
  }
}
```

Change the test to use `Task` instead

```
public async Task TestDetachedRecordsArentUpdatedWithoutIDs() {

    //...

}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)